# Unable to split the named groups as columns for date format using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to extract the date format from text read as pandas' `Series` object. I have successfully written the regex for extracting all complex date formats, but I'm facing a huge pain point in extracting the groups as named groups. The main issue is that I've used non-capturing groups in expression making it difficult to get them as named groups.

The **output** I require is of the form of dataframe with columns as **extracted entire date followed by year, month and date**. The sample input is as follows:

```
df5 = pd.Series(
    ["04/20/2009", "04/20/09", "4/20/09", "4/3/09", "Mar-20-2009", 
     "Mar 20, 2009", "March 20, 2009", "Mar. 20, 2009", "Mar 20 2009", 
     "20 Mar 2009","20 March 2009", "20 Mar. 2009", "20 March, 2009", 
     "Mar 20th, 2009", "Mar 21st, 2009", "Mar 22nd, 2009", "Feb 2009", 
     "Sep 2009", "Oct 2010", "6/2008","12/2009", "2009", "2010"])
```

The expression I used to do for extraction is:

```
df5.str.extractall(r'((?:\d{1,2})?[/ ]*?(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z\., -/]*)?(?:\d{1,2}[a-z, -/]*)?\d{2,4})')
```

I'm unable to perform the subsequent steps of splitting date into year, month, and day. I've tried to split using `re.compile` and `re.search` but I'm unable to comprehend the error it throws,

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object.

P.S: I looked at lot of questions of similar nature from Stack Overflow in the likes of
[sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933353/regex-split-into-groups), [sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158859/python-regex-and-group-function). The date formats I've to extract are quite complex and I've tried almost for a week so please don't close the question as duplicate very easily.

Comment: what do you want in the `month` & `date` column when the source text does not have that granularity (e.g. the last 3 values in your series)? It would be more clear if you provided your expected output explicitly.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Oh yes. It can be assumed that by default in case of absence of month it corresponds to the first month and on absence of both day & month it can be assumed that 1st day of the 1st month.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the actual goal:

Instead of trying to come up with the regex, can you use a pre-existing function? If so, then just use `pd.to_datetime`. It successfully parsed your sample data

```
pd.to_datetime(df5)
# outputs:
0    2009-04-20
1    2009-04-20
2    2009-04-20
3    2009-04-03
4    2009-03-20
5    2009-03-20
6    2009-03-20
7    2009-03-20
8    2009-03-20
9    2009-03-20
10   2009-03-20
11   2009-03-20
12   2009-03-20
13   2009-03-20
14   2009-03-21
15   2009-03-22
16   2009-02-01
17   2009-09-01
18   2010-10-01
19   2008-06-01
20   2009-12-01
21   2009-01-01
22   2010-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

to extract the date components, you can use the `.dt` accessor

example full solution resulting in a dataframe:

```
pd.concat([
  df5.rename('date_str'),
  pd.to_datetime(df5).dt.year.rename('year'),
  pd.to_datetime(df5).dt.month.rename('month'),
  pd.to_datetime(df5).dt.date.rename('date')
], axis=1)

          date_str  year  month        date
0       04/20/2009  2009      4  2009-04-20
1         04/20/09  2009      4  2009-04-20
2          4/20/09  2009      4  2009-04-20
3           4/3/09  2009      4  2009-04-03
4      Mar-20-2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
5     Mar 20, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
6   March 20, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
7    Mar. 20, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
8      Mar 20 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
9      20 Mar 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
10   20 March 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
11    20 Mar. 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
12  20 March, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
13  Mar 20th, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-20
14  Mar 21st, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-21
15  Mar 22nd, 2009  2009      3  2009-03-22
16        Feb 2009  2009      2  2009-02-01
17        Sep 2009  2009      9  2009-09-01
18        Oct 2010  2010     10  2010-10-01
19          6/2008  2008      6  2008-06-01
20         12/2009  2009     12  2009-12-01
21            2009  2009      1  2009-01-01
22            2010  2010      1  2010-01-01
```

---

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object.

This above error indicates that the type of the column is `bytes` instead of `str`.

This example code will throw the same exception

```
re.findall('hello', b'hello kitty')
```

bytes have to be pattern matched against bytes, or decoded first to str and then pattern matched with a string pattern, so, the two ways to *fix* the line above are to either replace the pattern with `b'hello'` or to decode the source string to something (e.g. `b'hello kitty'.decode('ascii') # 'utf8' would also work`).

To decode the bytes column to a str, you can use the `str` accessor and use the `decode method as shown above

example

```
df5.str.decode('utf8')
```

However, I'm not sure that your regex will work, but am not attempting to fix that bit as I believe your goal can be achieved with less complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm implementing this as a part of an assignment in getting to know the regex expressions. The final suggestion of converting the bytes into string or string into bytes? Will it work on pd.Series?